# jstl conditional not working

Tags: jstl, conditional-statements

I'm trying to separate my Java Code from my JSP files and I'm having a bit of a problem. I'm trying to find out whether the user is a guest or not and then printing the appropriate action EG login form or their Username.

Heres my index.jsp file:

```
<% if(view.guest) { %>
<%= "Scriptlet: Login Form Here" %>
<% } else { %>
<%= "Scriptlet: User Name Here" %>
<% } %>

<br/><br/>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${view.guest eq true}">
JSTL Tag: Login Form Here
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
JSTL Tag: User Name Here
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

This produces the following output:

Scriptlet: Login Form

JSTL Tag: User Name

As you can see the Scriptlet produces the expected results, but the JSTL tags produce the opposite. Infact  if I reverse the JSTL's conditional to false (for debugging purposes) it still produces the same result "JSTL Tag: User Name"

Btw view.guest is a public boolean variable of the object view.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP EL doesn't access local variables. It accesses attributes of the page, request, session or application scope. And it also assumes you're not using public fields (which should never be used), but respect the Java Bean conventions.

And, just as in Java, comparing a boolean with true is unnecessary. You just need

```
<c:when test="${view.guest}">
```

And the condition will evaluate to true if there is a page, request, session or application attribute named "view", having a public `getGuest()` or `isGuest()` method returning true.

If you didn't use scriptlets at all, you would never have local variables in your pages, and you would never have this problem.

Comment: I used <c:when test="${view.guest}"> and it didn't work

Is there any way of testing against a variable from an object?

Comment: I fixed a mistake in my answer. re-read it. But forget definitely about public fields, and about scriptlets.

Comment: Ok so added this in my CodeProjects.java file:

public boolean isGuest(){return guest;}

and it's still giving the same results

Comment: But do you have an instance of this CodeProjects class in an attribute named "view", in the page, request, session or application scope?

Comment: Yeah. I instantiate the class in my index.jsp file at the top of the page as follows:

<% CodeProjects view = new CodeProjects(session.getAttribute("auth")); %>

It takes a single argument for the constructor which determines whether the user has a valid authentication hash code from session.getAttribute("auth"). If that returns null it assumes a Guest is visiting. Then boolean method view.isGuest() is called in JSTL... which won't work. However it works in a scriptlet.

Comment: So you don't have any attribute named "view" in any scope. You have a local variable named `view`. You need an attribute: `pageContext.setAttribute("view", view);` or `request.setAttribute("view", view);` or `session.setAttribute("view", view);`. If you stopped using scriptlets, you would realize that the only way to transfer objects from a Java class (a servlet, for example) to a JSP is to put this object in a request or session attribute. That's what the EL expects, and that's where it looks for objects. Not in local variables, because they are created by scriptlets, which should NOT be used

Comment: Finally I've got it working thanks to you!! :) I used pageContext.setAttribute as you advised and now my JSTL tags can access my view object's methods. A few more questions...

How can avoid initializing my view object and using pageContext.setAttrubute() in scriptlet tags? Can it be done in JSTL or useBean ? Thanks again

Comment: You should do that in Java code, in a controller servlet for example. The request goes to the servlet, which validates the request, gets data from a database, creates objects and stores them in request attributes. Then the servlet forwards to a JSP, which uses the JSTL and the EL (and no scriptlet) to display the objects that are in the request attributes.

Comment: Can I include a servlet into a JSP IE in my index.jsp page? like this: <%@  page import="package.aServlet" %>

Then the imported servlet can initialize objects and set pageContext attributes so the JSTL tags inside the JSP can invoke them.

Comment: Importing a class doesn't execute any code. It just allows using this class without writing its full name. No, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Yeah I thought that. How could I automatically invoke a servlet which handles pagecontext attributes when a user visits index.jsp which is the default page of my website? Would I have to make a default servlet called Index which sets attributes then redirects the user to index.jsp?

Comment: Yes, except it should not redirect, but forward to index.jsp.

Comment: Whats the difference between redirect and forward? If I use redirect to index.jsp would I lose the attributes, but forward would retain them?

Comment: I thought I'd ask you instead lol. But yeah I'll do that. Cheers.